# Can I add AND after joining 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, join

Is this a legal MySql query? (More precisely, the part where I´m joining 2 tables and adding a AND condition.)

```
LEFT JOIN release_artwork ON release_artwork.album_id = album.album_id AND release_artwork.position = 1
```

Here is the complete query:

```
SELECT album.album_id, album.title, country.country_id, artwork.thumb_filename, artwork.thumb_width, artwork.thumb_height
FROM song
JOIN album ON song.published_album = album.album_id
LEFT JOIN country ON album.country_id = country.country_id
LEFT JOIN release_artwork ON release_artwork.release_id = album.album_id AND release_artwork.position = 1
LEFT JOIN artwork ON artwork.artwork_id = release_artwork.artwork_id
WHERE song.song_id = 1
```

Can I add `AND` right after joining 2 tables?

Comment: Does it work when you try it?  It logically seems reasonable.

Comment: Did you try to do it to see what you get?

Comment: Yes you can add **AND** to join two tables

Comment: `AND` is part of the `WHERE` conditional block so you can add as many conditions with `AND` as you like.

Comment: Does it give an error that you ask if you can add? ;) +1 @David, N.B.

Comment: it works when i added after joining the 2 tables, but i dont get the results expected when i added at the end with the WHERE condition... Want it to make sure that it was good practice to added after joining 2 tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is completely legal. I dont think it will throw any error